# Dockerfile: build image using a dockerfile inside a base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile: build image using a dockerfile inside a base image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM image1:latest
# image1 has a dockfile /usr/local/app/Dockerfile
docker -f /usr/local/app/Dockerfile
```

How to use the Dockerfile inside the base image1 to build the rest of the image?

Another way:

```
docker copy image1:latest:/usr/local/app/Dockerfile /tmp/Dockerfile
docker build -f /tmp/Dockerfile .
```

But docker do not have the copy command to copy files from an image out to host.

or using the dockerfile inside an image directly:

```
docker build -f image1:latest:/usr/local/app/Dockerfile .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: image1:latest:/usr/local/app/Dockerfile
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying ti achieve?

Comment: The base image is a library/package that provides a Dockerfile for building application image.

Comment: Either copy the file out of the base image and run it or if you need to build the docker image inside the base image then the base image would need to support docker in docker (DIND). However you shouldn't use base images to pass other dockerfikes around. This is what remote version control systems are for.

Comment: You can build your image `FROM` the image built by the other Dockerfile, or `COPY --from=` the other image, but you can't directly import or invoke its Dockerfile.